# Java Swing - Lines beyond the first drawn are on a separate layer

Tags: java, swing

I'm building a Java Swing application where I'm attempting to draw multiple lines on a map to represent waypoints.  These waypoints are usually intersecting in the form that the end of one waypoint is the start of another.  My issue is that only the first drawn line will ever appear as intended, and the other(s) will be "floating" around on what appears to be another layer (see image).  I'm not quite sure why this is the case, since shouldn't the code be drawing the line on the same Graphics2D object?  I saw in some somewhat-related questions that there were issues of implicit JPanel creation leading to somewhat similar issues, but I don't think that should be the case here? Any help would be appreciated.

```
private void drawRoute( final Graphics2D g, final JXMapViewer map, List<List<? extends GeoPosition>> tracks)
{
    for (List<? extends GeoPosition> track : tracks) {

        int lastX = 0;
        int lastY = 0;

        boolean first = true;

        for (GeoPosition gp : track)
        {
            // convert geo-coordinate to world bitmap pixel
            Point2D pt = map.getTileFactory().geoToPixel(gp, map.getZoom());

            if (first)
            {
                first = false;
            }
            else
            {
                double curX = pt.getX();
                double curY = pt.getY();
                Line2D.Double testLine = new Line2D.Double(lastX, lastY, curX, curY);
                //g.drawLine(lastX, lastY, (int) curX, (int) curY);
                g.draw(testLine);
            }

            lastX = (int) pt.getX();
            lastY = (int) pt.getY();
        }
    }
}

private void paintLeg( final Leg start, final Leg end, final Graphics2D graphics,
                           final JXMapViewer map , Optional<Color> color)
    {   
        Point2D pointStart = map.getTileFactory().geoToPixel(positionToGeo(start.terminatorPosition()),
                                                             map.getZoom());

        Point2D pointEnd = map.getTileFactory().geoToPixel(positionToGeo(end.terminatorPosition()),
                                                           map.getZoom());

        Line2D.Double line = new Line2D.Double(pointStart, pointEnd);

        Rectangle clipBounds = map.getViewportBounds();
        if (clipBounds.contains(pointStart) || clipBounds.contains(pointEnd) || clipBounds.intersectsLine(line))
        {
            List<GeoPosition> track = new ArrayList<>();

            double[] curCoords = new double[2]; // hold the waypoint coords
            curCoords[0] = start.terminatorPosition().latitudeDegrees();
            curCoords[1] = start.terminatorPosition().longitudeDegrees();                
            GeoPosition startPosition = new GeoPosition(curCoords);
            track.add(startPosition);
            curCoords[0] = end.terminatorPosition().latitudeDegrees();
            curCoords[1] = end.terminatorPosition().longitudeDegrees();
            GeoPosition endPosition = new GeoPosition(curCoords);
            track.add(endPosition);

            // convert from viewport to world bitmap
            Rectangle rect = map.getViewportBounds();
            graphics.translate(-rect.x, -rect.y);

            tracks.add(track);

            // do the drawing
            if (color.isPresent()) {
                graphics.setColor(color.get());
            }
            else {
                graphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            }
            graphics.setStroke(new BasicStroke(4));

            drawRoute(graphics, map, tracks);
        }
    }

@Override
    protected void doPaint( final Graphics2D graphics, final JXMapViewer map,
                            final int width, final int height )
    {
        // API doesn't provide any guarantee on nullability of these arguments. To be
        // safe, check this and do nothing if so.
        if ((graphics != null) && (map != null))
        {
            Optional<Color> color = Optional.empty();
            Optional<Integer> startAndEnd = Optional.empty();
            paintLegs(flightPlanLegs, graphics, map, color, startAndEnd, startAndEnd);
        }
    }

private final JXMapKit          map               = new JXMapKit();
private final FixPainter        fixPainter        = new FixPainter();
private final RoutePainter      routePainter      = new RoutePainter();
private final DataCreditPainter dataCreditPainter = new DataCreditPainter();
private Iterable<? extends Fix> databaseFixes     = ImmutableList.of();
private Iterable<? extends Fix> selectedFixes     = ImmutableList.of();
private Iterable<? extends Leg> flightPlanLegs    = ImmutableList.of();
private List<List<? extends GeoPosition>> tracks  = ArrayList<>();

 private void initializeMap()
{
    map().setDefaultProvider(DefaultProviders.OpenStreetMaps);
    map().setDataProviderCreditShown(true);

    // Create a compound painter for all of the painters
    CompoundPainter<JXMapViewer> painter =
        new CompoundPainter<>(ImmutableList.of(fixPainter, dataCreditPainter,
                                               routePainter));
    painter.setCacheable(false);

    map().getMainMap().setOverlayPainter(painter);
    map().setTileFactory(MapBoxTileFactoryInfo.newTileFactory());

    zoom(DEFAULT_ZOOM);
    replaceFlightPlan(null);
}

void replaceFlightPlan( final Iterable<? extends Leg> legs )
{
  Leg fpl1 = new Leg()
  {

      @Override
      public Position terminatorPosition()
      {
          return Position.of(47, -122);
      }

      @Override
      public String identifier()
      {
          return "fpl1";
      }
  };
  Leg fpl2 = new Leg()
  {

      @Override
      public Position terminatorPosition()
      {
          return Position.of(48, -111);
      }

      @Override
      public String identifier()
      {
          return "fpl2";
      }
  };
  Leg fpl3 = new Leg()
  {

      @Override
      public Position terminatorPosition()
      {
          return Position.of(32, -111);
      }

      @Override
      public String identifier()
      {
          return "fpl3";
      }
  };
  ArrayList<Leg> ok = new ArrayList<>();
  ok.add(fpl1);
  ok.add(fpl2);
  ok.add(fpl3);
  flightPlanLegs = ImmutableList.copyOf(ok);
  Iterator<List<? extends GeoPosition>> tracksItr = tracks.iterator();
  while (tracksItr.hasNext()) {
      tracksItr.remove();
  }
}
```

[image: photo of current behavior]

The line over by the UK should be starting where the line in the US ends.

Comment: Post a [mcve]..

Comment: @user1803551 I believe my latest edit should add enough context to make it easier to understand the general layout without overloading on the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out the code works... Eclipse simply wasn't building the maven project properly.  I had to manually run "mvn clean install" on the command line for the project for changes to properly take place. I'm leaving this question up for the moment as it may help someone else out, but if it's recommended to take down, I'll delete it.